# Sqlalchemy: How do I update a parent record in a joined table inheritance

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update a record in a joined table inheritance but am getting an error saying the column does not exists (since it's technically in the parent table).  This is using Flask-Sqlalchemy / Postgres.

**Models**
(Joined Table Inheritance):

```
class Job:
    __tablename__ = "job"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    currency = db.Column(db.Float)
    type = db.Column(db.String(100))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "type",
        "polymorphic_on": type,
    }

    ...


class Plumber(Career):
    __tablename__ = "plumber"

    glue_type = db.Column(db.String(100))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "plumber",
    }
    ...
```

**Query:**

```
Plumber.query.filter_by({"currency":"USD"}).update({"currency":"Euro", "glue_type":"acrylic"))
db.session.commit()
```

**Error**

`(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "currency" of relation "plumber" does not exist`

**Question**

Is it possible to update the Plumber table with data found in the `plumber` table and the `job` table in one query? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
update_data = {"currency":"Euro", "glue_type":"acrylic")

inst = Plumber.query.filter_by({"currency":"USD"}).first()

for col, val in update_data.items():
  setattr(inst, col, val)

db.session.commit()
```